# Automapper deletes all arrays when mapping same class

Tags: c#, automapper, repository-pattern

I have the following class

```
public class Unit
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("unittype")]
    public UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("managers")]
    public List<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("logoURL")]
    public string LogoURL { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("naceCodeList")
    public List<string> NaceCodeList { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string JoinedTags => string.Join(",", Tags);
    [JsonProperty("respondents")]
    public List<Respondent> Respondents { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("childUnits")]
    public List<Unit> ChildUnits { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following in the constructor of my BaseRepository

```
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Unit, Unit>();
        });
```

My problem is that when I, in my repository, do `Mapper.Map(unitToUpdate, unit);` it empties all the `List<whatever>` properties.

Is this default behavior? Am I doing something wrong here?

For completeness, here is my UpdateUnit function

```
    public void UpdateUnit(ClaimsPrincipal user, string orgId, Unit unitToUpdate)
    {
        var org = Get(user, orgId);
        var unit = org.GetUnit(unitToUpdate.Id);
        Mapper.Map(unitToUpdate, unit);
        Update(user, org);
    }
```

The stored object is another type containing a hierarchy of `Unit` objects representing a company. The `org` object is what is stored in the database, and the class representing the `org` object has it's own functions to load `Unit` objects inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is that you need first to define the mappings for all collections from both objects and after that you need to define the mappings for objects.

Idea is to get from the bottom to the top (from the nested one to the Unit).

For example (taking into consideration only Respondents:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RespondentDb, RespondentDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UnitDb, UnitDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Respondents, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Respondents);
```

Some references:

1. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings
2. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70856/automapper-mapping-a-nested-collection-to-a-list (here we have an object that only contains a list, maybe it's good to know that too as you can encounter the same scenario)

Comment: But it's the same class.. I'm mapping from Unit to Unit. It's just that one is fresh from the database, and one is modified from the mvc controller calling it.

Comment: I really don't know about this scenario because i didn't used mapping from/to the same class. I know there were some problems some time ago related to doing that, so i avoided (one example: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/656)

Comment: Maybe it's better to create a github issue too as this isn't so well documented and can relate to some internal paths that we're chosen in development.

Comment: You can also give it a try creating a map from Respondent to Respondent. And then one from Unit to Unit also specifying the ForMember method. And please get back to me in order to remove this answer.